Calculate ephemeris for Mars before 1600 in Stellarium
I am trying to calculate Mars' ephemeris for XVI century (specifically from 1570 to 1599). However, Stellarium only allows calculations beyond 1600. Is there optional package that I can install to obtain the Mars' ephemeris for the range I 1570-1599 using Stellarium? I am a Windows 10 user.

Can you mention the version number of the Stellarium you are using, and the platform (computer, phone, etc.)? This FAQ says "Stellarium can simulate from -4999 to 4999 years." Here is a list of available plug-in modules and I don't see anything about date extension.

I am using Stellarium 0.20.1 in Windows 10 machine. I can travel in time. But I would like to calculate the ephemerides to plot 9-months trajectories of Mars in 1570, 1571, 1572, ..., 1599. I am seeking for kind of trajectories at the retrograde motions. I can easily calculate the trajectores beyond 1600, but not before 1600 :/

Using Stellarium 24.1 on macOS, the earliest possible date is October 15, 1582 (the start of the Gregorian calendar).

Woow, thank you! I will update my version. But it would be great if it allowed me to calculate the ephemerides of ealier dates...

Stellarium isn't an astrometry package, I would recommend using JPL Horizons to generate positions: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/app.html#/ .  Last I looked at the Stellarium source code, it used the JPL Development Ephemeris for recent times, then fell back to the less accurate VSOP87 for more distant times.  That may still be accurate enough for your use case, but you might want to look into it.  If you just use JPL Horizons, you don't have to worry about it though.

Even using Horizons you can't get Mars itself before 1600 AD, but you can get the Mars system barycenter from 9999 BC to 9999 AD. For most purposes, the barycenter should be adequate. See https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/time_spans.html

@PM2Ring I can't imagine a purpose for which the difference between the Mars "Geocenter" and Martian system barycenter would be important for dates before 1600 AD. I guess by "most purposes" you're just being careful. (Nor can I imagine that they would differ more than the expected error inherent in the ephemeris, the motion of those little, low-flying Moons must have some significant uncertainties)

@uhoh Yes, I'm just being careful. Phobos and Deimos don't perturb Mars very much. ;)

https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJw1kV1r2zAUhu%5FPrzhVA7XBUeL0OyCom8mrxxxnsTZob4xqK7GGPzRL3spK%5F%5FtIul4envecF55zig%5F9oP%5F2ncVn6cqa4ibFxVZ3%2DwAX88UFnd%5FQxRXo1vSDw0H9GpV1FsahQYakds7Y5WxmbUV%5FmoZ20kq673%5FPpNGz%2Dv%5FhYqcbRaXRBKBsq8MeISeTSZ7FsMrSNFp%5FYhew4mvBt%2Dzu%5FPYWchFtRSGSlLOz8PJ6Pv0iu2mIQpxBLrLNOzmCWD1PQ8gF3xR58sRZWMG379FaJCLhOTsPYRV9LeJsm0aC3Wfi4TiLxw1nn2GV%5F%5FhAjzyHk8mEZzEQQgDudOfUIEsHldph4R3VsKQzo7vvX7yyrQL8oytXs6t5gLXS%2D9qx8NIPUI6uL0ZTSadYLBur%5FCUgIppBd8778EdNb503Dk2AlXSSvZJdP7TSkSUSp14ceQvwYM2yV6IPrWSJHinbigTvb%5FLffHoI%2DvAPsP6H8w==&lang=sage
